# Speeding up the load time of a Java Applet in a browser control

Tags: jvm

We have an application which occasionally has to communicate with an external service using a browser control. Navigating to a specific address fires up a Java applet which then communicates with our application via a socket which we open and listen on. I have no control over the website or the java applet.

The problem is that the first time this is done, the java applet takes an unacceptably long time to load, after this initial first load it is very responsive. The machines that the software runs on automatically reboot every night so this problem is going to occur at least once a day for the customer.

I don't know anything about Java or applets but from what Ive read the delay is down to the initial loading of the JVM and then the applet itself.

Is there any way to speed up this process, perhaps there's a way to pre load the JVM which might be enough?